# Phonegap iPad app screen can be moved

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, cordova, window

On iPad, whole application window of my app, built by jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap, can be moved by tapping and dragging. When finger is released the app window repositioned itself. How can I lock the app window so it does not move upon tapping & dragging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS

**Cordova.plist**

> a. UIWebViewBounce (boolean, defaults to YES) - set to NO if you don't
>   want the WebView to rubber-band